# Can i select a rotation direction in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need animate a figure in two directions. How can I set clockwise or counterclockwise directions for animation?

```
return new Promise(
  ((resolve, reject) => figure.animate({
    angle: nextAngle
  }, {
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    onComplete: resolve,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: fabric.util.ease.easeInQuad
  }))
)
```

UPD. I'm found how I can recalculate an angle.

```
let currentAngle = figure.get('angle');
if(Math.abs(currentAngle - nextAngle) > 180) {
  if(nextAngle < 0) {
    nextAngle += 360;
  } else {
    nextAngle -= 360;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the setAngle() method? One imagines that using negative number with this method causes the object to rotate counter clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem for trying to take the shortest route to reset the angle of an object. Fixed it in this small if/else clause:

```
if(options.target.angle < 180 ) {
     options.target.animate('angle', 0, { onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
   } else {
     var distance = 360 - options.target.angle;
     options.target.animate("angle", '+='+distance, { onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)});
   }
   options.target.angle = 0;
```